# API to get all the reviews and rating from Google for business

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API to get the reviews and ratings for a company.

Step 1: HTTP Request to get the reference Id.

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query='.<CompanyName>.'&sensor=true&key='.<apikey>;
```

After HTTP request I am getting referenceId of business.

Step 2: HTTP request to get the reviews.

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference='.<referenceId>.'&key='.<apiKey>
```

With the above, I am getting the "most helpful reviews" and a maximum of 5 reviews.

So I want to get all the reviews or the latest reviews. Do I need to add a parameter?

Comment: Any update here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should need to use the Google My Business API if you want to get all the reviews.

It's another different API, and you should request from Google the property of the place.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

Comment: Actually I want the all reviews and ratings of any company not the single company.

Comment: The company name would be dynamic.

Comment: If the place it's not yours obviously you won't have access to the My Bussiness API for that place. The Google Maps API gives a maximum of 5 reviews only. You can play with the language parameter, but you will only receive 5 reviews for each language you request. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details?hl=en-419

Comment: Yep. we are using the same currently it provides only 5 reviews with most helpful reviews. So, Is there any way to get all reviews or latest reviews.

Comment: With the maps API I'm sorry to say you it's not possible. Check the API link I placed in the previous comment. It says `reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews`

Comment: oops, Any Idea to get all the reviews?

Comment: I tried to see how google gets the reviews in google maps, it uses a url like this: https://www.google.es/maps/preview/reviews?authuser=0&hl=es&pb=xxxx The only way I think you can try to do it's using cURL or other system to get the page of one place, and extract this link which returns the reviews in JSON format.

Comment: Not helpful yet.

Comment: How to use that URL to get reviews: google.es/maps/preview/reviews?authuser=0&hl=es&pb=xxxx

Comment: is there any third party service that can provide all the reviews?

Comment: How can I get accountId for this request: GET
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews
Does it also require me to set up oAuth?

Comment: Swapnil agashe: I don't know, but I think Google don't gives the full info to anyone excluding this API.
Camel: You need to create one Google Cloud Console account, and create credentials.

Comment: @ManeeshRao Did you get any final solution to import reviews of any business account using My Business API of google ?

Comment: @NetVicious Hi , i am facing this same topic,,, not sure if the API is still applicable or it has been deprecated as the message indicate inside this link @  https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews . second question, is this API free or it is paid? Thanks

Comment: @johnGu the Bussiness API it's free at this moment (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/pricing?hl=es-419). The end-point we should use it's the same, but it seems they changed a bit the returned JSON, you can check the changes here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates

Answer (score 9):

Other simple method to get the 5 last rewiews with the place_id of the location (you can find it here : https://developers.google.com/places/place-id)

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=Yourkey&placeid=YourplaceID";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
$res        = json_decode($result,true);
$reviews    = $res['result']['reviews'];
```

Comment: Not last 5, it returns random 5 reviews.

Comment: Although it seem to should've worked, but apparently it has become a paid service, because I get message starting with "You must enable Billing..."

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Google provides up to five results only, they mentioned it in their documentation.
If you want to get reviews for your own property/place or business you can go for my business but I think they made that API closed one.

Edit: If you still want to fetch all reviews you can use an HTML parser and parse all the reviews(i don't know about Google's data policy, but you can definitely scrape everything from a site)

Comment: is there any third party service that can provide all the reviews?

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/335542/57334

Answer (score 2):

There is a third party solution like SerpApi that you can use to get all reviews of any place. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Each page fatches 10 results. To implement the pagination just use the `start` parameter which defines the result offset (e.g., `0` (default) is the first page of results, `10` is the 2nd page of results, `20` is the 3rd page of results, etc.)

```php
require 'path/to/google_search_results';

$query = [
  "engine" => "google_maps_reviews",
  "place_id" => "0x89c259a61c75684f:0x79d31adb123348d2",
  "api_key" => "SECRET_API_KEY"
];

$search = new GoogleSearch();
$results = $search->json($query);
$reviews = $result->reviews;
```

Example output:

```json
"reviews": [
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Waylon Bilbrey",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/107691056156160235121?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUituIlpTvAhVYCc0KHbvTCrgQvvQBegQIARAx",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjOj6Wjfk1kSYjhvH7WIBNMdl4nPj6FvUhvYcR6=s40-c0x00000000-cc-rp",
      "reviews": 1
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "date": "a week ago",
    "snippet": "I've been here multiple times. The coffee itself is just average to me. The service is good (the people working are nice). The aesthetic is obviously what brings the place some fame. A little overpriced (even for NY). A very small cup for $6 where I feel like the price comes from the top rainbow foam decor , when I'm going to cover it anyways. If it's for an insta pic then it may be worth it?"
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Amber Grace Sale",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106390058588469541899?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUituIlpTvAhVYCc0KHbvTCrgQvvQBegQIARA7",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj84nHu_9V_0V4yRbZcr-8ZTYAHua6gUBP8fC7W=s40-c0x00000000-cc-rp-ba3",
      "local_guide": true,
      "reviews": 33,
      "photos": 17
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "date": "2 years ago",
    "snippet": "They really take pride in their espresso roast here and the staff is extremely knowledgeable on the subject. It’s also a GREAT place to do work although a table is no guarantee; you might have to wait for a bit. My almond milk cappuccino was very acidic at the end which wasn’t expected but I could still tell the bean was high quality. Their larger lattés they put in a tall glass cup which looks really really cool. Would definitely go again.",
    "likes": 2,
    "images": [
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMup24_dHrWtNN4ZD70EPsiRMf_tykcUkPw6A1H=w100-h100-p-n-k-no"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Kelvin Petar",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100859090874785206875?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUituIlpTvAhVYCc0KHbvTCrgQvvQBegQIARBG",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhdIvUDamzfPqbYIpwhnGJV2XWSi77iVXfEsiKS=s40-c0x00000000-cc-rp",
      "reviews": 3
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "date": "3 months ago",
    "snippet": "Stumptown Cafe is the perfect place to work or catch up with friends. Never too loud, never too dead. Their lattes and deliciously addicting and the toasts are tasty as well. Wifi is always fast, which is a huge plus! The staff are the friendliest, I highly recommend this place!"
  },
  ...
]
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-reviews-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*